# What does x equal?

Tags: products

I have 4 numbers -- a, b, c, and d -- that I can pair up in 6 different ways to multiply -- a*b, a*c, a*d, b*c, b*d, c*d .when I do, I get products in the set {5, 6, 10, 12, 18, x}. what does x equal ?

My solution was as follows:

$cd = \frac{(ac)(bd)}{ab} = \frac{6 * 18}{5} = \frac{108}{5}$

or

$cd = \frac{(ad)(bc)}{ab} = \frac{10 * 12}{5} = 24$

I solved some of the equations together to get these values of (a, b, c)
$(\frac{\sqrt{10}}{2}, \sqrt{10}, \frac{6 \sqrt{10}}{5})$

Now if I use these values to get d, I get two different values:

if I used the equation $ad = 10$ thus $d = 2 \sqrt{10}$ and $cd = \frac{6 \sqrt{10}}{5} * 2 \sqrt{10} = 24$

if I used the equation $bd = 18$ thus $d = \frac{9 \sqrt{10}}{5}$ and $cd = \frac{6 \sqrt{10}}{5} * \frac{9 \sqrt{10}}{5} = \frac{108}{5}$

Is this solution correct?
I got confused that there could be more than one value for x!

Comment: Without having done any more work, yes it's possible that there are multiple solutions. Can you show what you've tried, and where you're stuck at? Hint: Consider the value of $abcd$.

Comment: Did you find any tuple $(a,b,c,d)$ so far with products in this set?

Comment: @CalvinLin I edited the question to include how I solved it, can you please confirm if it's correct. Thanks.

Comment: Using factoring, since one of the products is a $5$,  that two of the four numbers are $1$ and $5$. Can you work the rest of them out?

Comment: @DietrichBurde sorry, I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: You need to find four integers $a,b,c,d$, so that the products are in your set. Can you give one possible example of such integers $a,b, c,d$? If you want $5$ as a product, then your tuple is of the form $(1,5,c,d)$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks for the clarification, now I understand, that was actually helpful. and now I understand why there are two different possible values of x.

Comment: Your mistake is that you assumed they listed the products in order, so that ab = 5, ac = 6, etc. They did not, and the fact that you got two inconsistent values for cd proves that this approach is wrong.

Comment: @MinhĐứcHoàng You seem to be assuming that these numbers must be integers. They need not be.

Comment: @DietrichBurde We need to find four numbers, not 4 integers. $ ab = 5$ could be factored in many ways.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I edited the question, can you check now?

Comment: @CalvinLin can you check the solution after I edited the post, is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To answer if this solution was correct before the edit**, as pointed out in the comments, the mistake made by OP is assuming that the products are given in order, which they need not be. Such an assumption led to an inconsistent system, which is why OP calculated differing values.

**To answer if this solution was correct after the edit**, the mistake made by OP is that they didn't verify that they had a consistent system (which they didn't).
EG For $ (a, b, c) = ( \frac{ \sqrt{10}}{2} , \sqrt{10}, \frac{ 6\sqrt{10}}{5})$, if $ ad = 10$, then $ d= 2\sqrt{10}$. But then,  we do not have 2 terms whose product is 18, so this doesn't satisfy the conditions of the problem.

---

**To answer the problem that was posed,** the hint I provided, was to consider what the value of $abcd$ is.  The solution sketch follows, fill in any gaps as needed.

1. $abcd =  ab \times cd = ac \times bd = ad \times bc$.
2. Out of the 5 given products, we must find two pairs of products which multiply to the same value. This will be a possible value of $abcd$.
3. Hence, conclude that the only possible value of $abcd$ is $ 5 \times 12 = 10 \times 6 = 18 \times x$.
4. Thus, the missing term is $ x = \frac{10}{3}$.

   - Because there is only 1 way to get $abcd$, this missing term is uniquely determined. See below for more details.
5. For completeness, let's establish that this system is consistent (else the answer is "no solution exists"). Solving $ ab = 5, ac = 10, ad = 18, abcd = 60$ gives us $ a = \sqrt{15}, b = \sqrt{5/3}, c = \sqrt{20/3} d = \sqrt{ 108/5}$. (Unique up to sign)

   - There are more solution sets that satisfy the original conditions, like taking $ ab = 5, ac = 10, ad = \frac{10}{3}, abcd = 60$.

---

**To answer OP's question of "could there be multiple answers"**, then this would require multiple sets of "two pairs which have the some product", which give multiple possible values of $abcd$, which hopefully might give multiple possible values of $x$.

As an explicit example, if the products in the set were $\{1, 2, 4, 8, 16, x \}$, then by following the steps in the above solution, we could have:

- $1 \times 16 = 2 \times 8 = 4 \times x$, so the missing term is $x  = 4$.   This can be achieved by $ a = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, b = \sqrt{2}, c = 2\sqrt{2}, d = 4 \sqrt{2}$.
- $ 1 \times 8 = 2 \times 4 = 16 \times x $, so the missing term is $x = \frac{1}{2}$. This can be achieved by $ a = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2} }, b = \sqrt{2} , c = 2\sqrt{2} , d = 4\sqrt{2} $.

Comment: abcd is 5×12=10×6=60 can you please clarify this part?

Comment: @MoazNasem Can you clarify what you do not understand about it? Make sure you read and understood the prior steps too.

Comment: I read it again and again, now I understand why my solution is wrong and I understood your solution, really appreciated it, thanks a lot.